# Just like string is object type is immutable?

Tags: c#

I am trying to understand difference between value type and reference type and have doubt where i am not able to understand differnce between Person class (User defined data type) and Object type.

When i do `Person p1 = new Person();p1.Name = "Ashu";` "Ashu" will be stored in heap and after `p2 = p1;`, p2 will look at this memory and any alteration using p2 will also change p1 as both are pointing at same memory.

```
          // Just a demo which shows data changed for ref type
        Person p1 = new Person();
        Person p2 = new Person();
        p1.Id = 10;
        p2 = p1;
        p2.Id = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(p1.Id);  // Output 20
```

Why above principal is not true for below example as object is also reference type

```
        // Same example when type is "Object"
        object obj1 = new object();
        object obj2 = new object();
        obj1 = 10;
        obj2 = obj1;
        obj2 = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(obj1); // Output 10
```

Comment: Because you don't modify a property of `obj2` but you replace it completely with something else. From now on there's no relation between `obj1` and `obj2` anymore, both variables reference different objects.

Comment: If i understand your comment correctly, I performed the test using only int and string...Where int is a value type and string is immutable hence I am getting a new copy every time. Right?

Comment: as it happens, `object` *is* immutable because it has no properties you can mutate - but that is moot - this code isn't about immutability; it is simply about the difference between a: changing properties of an object *at the end of a reference* vs b: changing the reference itself (to a different reference)

Comment: The reason you see `10` as the output of your second program is that you don't actually change `obj1` - it's still `10`. What you do change is `obj2`.

Comment: @A.Learn "Where int is a value type and string is immutable hence I am getting a new copy every time. Right?" - completely unrelated topic; both integers and strings are (essentially) immutable, one is a value-type, one is a reference-type, but: none of this matters to the question, since the issue *isn't about these things*

Comment: @A.Learn: No, you got it wrong. It's not about immutabity, value- or reference types at all. `obj2 = 20` will assign something else(a value type but it doesn't matter) to a variable. So the previous relation to `obj1` which you have linked with `obj2 = obj1` is gone. Now you could modify `obj1` or `obj2`(if possible) without affecting each other.

Comment: Thanks all of you, now I got it .... whenever I assigned 20 to obj2 ...I created new object in heap ... previous reference was removed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right; let's do this!

```
 Person p1 = new Person();
```

we now have one variable and one Person object (with Id = 0 by default)

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 0]
```

---

```
Person p2 = new Person();
```

We now have 2 variables and 2 objects (both with Id = 0 by default)

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 0]
p2 ---------------> [Person #1, Id = 0]
```

---

```
p1.Id = 10;
```

This *dereferences* the object via `p1` and sets the Id at the end:

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 10]
p2 ---------------> [Person #1, Id = 0]
```

---

```
p2 = p1;
```

This *overwrites the reference of p2* with the value from *p1*. No objects are created or destroyed in this operation, but now they both point to the same object:

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 10]
p2 -------------------/|\
```

(note the other object still exists somewhere, but we can not longer reach it; the GC will find it and kill it soon)

---

```
    p2.Id = 20;
```

This *dereferences* an object via the reference in p2. We only *have* one reachable object, so we shouldn't be surprised where we find ourselves:

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 20]
p2 -------------------/|\
```

---

```
    Console.WriteLine(p1.Id);  // Output 20
```

This *dereferences* the object via `p1` *which points to the same object*, so we output 20:

```
p1 ---------------> [Person #0, Id = 20]
p2 -------------------/|\
```

---

```
    object obj1 = new object();
```

This creates a new System.Object instance and assigns a reference to it to `obj1`:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Object #0]
```

---

```
object obj2 = new object();
```

This does the same thing - another new `Object` and new variable:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Object #0]
obj2 ---------------> [Object #1]
```

---

```
    obj1 = 10;
```

This creates *another* new object - this time a boxed integer:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Int32 #0, value 10]
obj2 ---------------> [Object #1]
```

---

```
    obj2 = obj1;
```

Copies this reference:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Int32 #0, value 10]
obj2 --------------------/|\
```

---

```
    obj2 = 20;
```

Creates another **new** object and assigns to `obj2`:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Int32 #0, value 10]
obj2 ---------------> [Int32 #1, value 20]
```

---

and finally

```
    Console.WriteLine(obj1); // Output 10
```

deferences `obj1` and finds the value 10:

```
obj1 ---------------> [Int32 #0, value 10]
obj2 ---------------> [Int32 #1, value 20]
```

---

The difference is that in first version, we were talking to the same object at the end; in the second version we are talking to 2 different objects (that happen to be immutable, but that isn't the point; we'd still see this behaviour if we had a mutable object; the difference is: assigning references vs mutating properties *via* a reference).

Answer (score 1):

When you use `=` like this:

```
p2 = p1;
```

you are changing what the variable on the right contains. In the above case, `p2` now stores a reference that points to the same object as the reference in `p1` does.

When you modify some property of an object:

p2.Id = 20;

You are not changing what `p2` contains. Rather, you are changing the object that `p2` is referring to.

This is exactly the reason why this does not work with `int`s. You cannot set any properties of an `int`. It is immutable. Even if it were mutable and exposed some property for you to set, you wouldn't see this effect because you can't set that property with a variable of type `object`.

What you are doing now is this:

```
obj2 = 20;
```

As I said before, using `=` like this is directly changing `obj2`. This means that you are making `obj2` point to something else, which is not what `obj1` is pointing to!

Answer (score 1):

For the statement `obj1 = 10;` the compiler determines that 10 is *not* an object. It treats the statement as `obj1 = (object)10;`.

When this gets executed, a **new object *containing* 10** is created on the heap.

For `obj2 = obj1;` the compiler determines that obj1 is of the same type as obj2, so it does just a pointer assignment.

Then `obj2 = 20;` happens, and a **new object *containing* 20** is created on the heap, for the same reasons as above.

In the end you have two new objects on the heap, one contains `10` and the other `20`, each with **1** variable pointing to them - next to the two objects that you started with (but which are now 'abandoned').